# Merging two xts to create NAs at certain time stamps

Tags: r, merge, xts

I have an irregular xts series where I want to include NAs at proper minutes eg.g 09:15:00, 09:16:00 and so on if these proper minutes are missing there. I am doing it through creating another series that has NA series with theses timestamps. 
This is my series:

```
dput(data1)
structure(c(108.4, 108.35, 108.35, 108.4, 108.2, 108.35, 108.25, 
108.25, 108.25, 108.25, 108.25, 108.25, 108.35, 108.3, 108.25, 
108.3, 108.25, 108.25, 108.2, 108.15, 108.2, 108.1, 108.25, 108.25, 
108.1, 108.2, 108.25, 108.15, 108.15, 108.1, 108.2, 108.1, 108.25, 
108.3, 108.25, 108.2, 108.2, 108.2, 108.1, 108.1, 108.1, 108.1, 
108.1, 108.15, 108.15, 108.05, 108.1, 108, 108, 108, 108.1, 108.05, 
108, 108.05, 108, 108.05, 107.9, 107.95, 107.85, 107.85, 107.85, 
107.85, 107.9, 107.9, 107.9, 108, 107.85, 107.9, 107.9, 107.9, 
108, 107.9, 108, 108, 108, 107.95, 107.95, 108, 108, 108, 108, 
107.95, 108, 108, 108, 108.05, 108.05, 108.1, 108.05, 108.1, 
108.1, 108.1, 108.1, 108.1, 108.15, 108.05, 108.1, 108.05, 108.05, 
108.05), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "Asia/Calcutta", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Calcutta", index = structure(c(1459481851, 
1459482301, 1459482303, 1459482304, 1459482305, 1459482306, 1459482307, 
1459482308, 1459482309, 1459482310, 1459482311, 1459482312, 1459482313, 
1459482314, 1459482315, 1459482316, 1459482317, 1459482318, 1459482319, 
1459482320, 1459482321, 1459482322, 1459482323, 1459482324, 1459482325, 
1459482326, 1459482327, 1459482328, 1459482329, 1459482330, 1459482331, 
1459482332, 1459482333, 1459482334, 1459482335, 1459482336, 1459482337, 
1459482339, 1459482340, 1459482341, 1459482342, 1459482343, 1459482344, 
1459482345, 1459482347, 1459482348, 1459482349, 1459482350, 1459482351, 
1459482352, 1459482353, 1459482354, 1459482355, 1459482356, 1459482357, 
1459482358, 1459482360, 1459482361, 1459482362, 1459482363, 1459482364, 
1459482365, 1459482366, 1459482367, 1459482368, 1459482369, 1459482370, 
1459482371, 1459482372, 1459482374, 1459482375, 1459482376, 1459482377, 
1459482378, 1459482379, 1459482380, 1459482381, 1459482382, 1459482384, 
1459482385, 1459482386, 1459482387, 1459482388, 1459482389, 1459482390, 
1459482392, 1459482393, 1459482394, 1459482395, 1459482396, 1459482397, 
1459482398, 1459482399, 1459482401, 1459482402, 1459482403, 1459482404, 
1459482405, 1459482406, 1459482407), tzone = "Asia/Calcutta", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(100L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "SYMBOL"), class = c("xts", "zoo"))
```

NA series:

```
    dput(NA.df)
structure(c(NA, NA, NA), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = structure("Asia/Calcutta", .Names = "TZ"), tzone = structure("Asia/Calcutta", .Names = "TZ"), index = structure(c(1459741500, 
1459741560, 1459741620), tzone = structure("Asia/Calcutta", .Names = "TZ"), tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(3L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "Empty"))
```

This is my code:

```
data2<-merge(data1,NA.df, all=TRUE)[,1:ncol(data1)]
```

This the result:

```
dput(data2)
structure(c(108.4, 108.35, 108.35, 108.4, 108.2, 108.35, 108.25, 
108.25, 108.25, 108.25, 108.25, 108.25, 108.35, 108.3, 108.25, 
108.3, 108.25, 108.25, 108.2, 108.15, 108.2, 108.1, 108.25, 108.25, 
108.1, 108.2, 108.25, 108.15, 108.15, 108.1, 108.2, 108.1, 108.25, 
108.3, 108.25, 108.2, 108.2, 108.2, 108.1, 108.1, 108.1, 108.1, 
108.1, 108.15, 108.15, 108.05, 108.1, 108, 108, 108, 108.1, 108.05, 
108, 108.05, 108, 108.05, 107.9, 107.95, 107.85, 107.85, 107.85, 
107.85, 107.9, 107.9, 107.9, 108, 107.85, 107.9, 107.9, 107.9, 
108, 107.9, 108, 108, 108, 107.95, 107.95, 108, 108, 108, 108, 
107.95, 108, 108, 108, 108.05, 108.05, 108.1, 108.05, 108.1, 
108.1, 108.1, 108.1, 108.1, 108.15, 108.05, 108.1, 108.05, 108.05, 
108.05, NA, NA, NA), index = structure(c(1459481851, 1459482301, 
1459482303, 1459482304, 1459482305, 1459482306, 1459482307, 1459482308, 
1459482309, 1459482310, 1459482311, 1459482312, 1459482313, 1459482314, 
1459482315, 1459482316, 1459482317, 1459482318, 1459482319, 1459482320, 
1459482321, 1459482322, 1459482323, 1459482324, 1459482325, 1459482326, 
1459482327, 1459482328, 1459482329, 1459482330, 1459482331, 1459482332, 
1459482333, 1459482334, 1459482335, 1459482336, 1459482337, 1459482339, 
1459482340, 1459482341, 1459482342, 1459482343, 1459482344, 1459482345, 
1459482347, 1459482348, 1459482349, 1459482350, 1459482351, 1459482352, 
1459482353, 1459482354, 1459482355, 1459482356, 1459482357, 1459482358, 
1459482360, 1459482361, 1459482362, 1459482363, 1459482364, 1459482365, 
1459482366, 1459482367, 1459482368, 1459482369, 1459482370, 1459482371, 
1459482372, 1459482374, 1459482375, 1459482376, 1459482377, 1459482378, 
1459482379, 1459482380, 1459482381, 1459482382, 1459482384, 1459482385, 
1459482386, 1459482387, 1459482388, 1459482389, 1459482390, 1459482392, 
1459482393, 1459482394, 1459482395, 1459482396, 1459482397, 1459482398, 
1459482399, 1459482401, 1459482402, 1459482403, 1459482404, 1459482405, 
1459482406, 1459482407, 1459516500, 1459516560, 1459516620), tzone = "Asia/Calcutta", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "Asia/Calcutta", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Calcutta", .Dim = c(103L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, "SYMBOL"))
```

But it does not has NA at 9:15:, 9:16:00, and so on. Please help me to find out where I am mistaking in my code. Thanks

Comment: I think you didn't match up the timezones correctly.

Comment: @42- I have changed the NA.df timezone but still the NA timestamps get added in the lastof the xts.

Comment: That's not surprising since the numerical values in the NA df are so much larger than those of the data1 index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is this:

```
> data2<-merge(data1, NA.df)
> tail(data2)
                    SYMBOL Empty
2016-04-01 09:16:45 108.05    NA
2016-04-01 09:16:46 108.05    NA
2016-04-01 09:16:47 108.05    NA
2016-04-04 09:15:00     NA    NA
2016-04-04 09:16:00     NA    NA
2016-04-04 09:17:00     NA    NA
```

Since you want NA's in `NA.df`, to see whats happening clearly, try this, which places by default 0 in the rows which do not match `SYMBOL` on `Empty`, instead of the default `NA`:

```
> data2<-merge(data1, NA.df, fill = 0)
> tail(data2)
                    SYMBOL Empty
2016-04-01 09:16:45 108.05     0
2016-04-01 09:16:46 108.05     0
2016-04-01 09:16:47 108.05     0
2016-04-04 09:15:00   0.00    NA
2016-04-04 09:16:00   0.00    NA
2016-04-04 09:17:00   0.00    NA
```

I think what you want is probably to have the NA's in the same column.  To do that, you need to have the same column name (`SYMBOL` here), and use `rbind`, not `merge` (`merge` will create two columns just like `cbind`, as it thinks they are distinct series, even though the column name is identical).

```
colnames(NA.df) <- "SYMBOL"
data2<-rbind(data1, NA.df)

> tail(data2, 6)
SYMBOL
2016-04-01 09:16:45 108.05
2016-04-01 09:16:46 108.05
2016-04-01 09:16:47 108.05
2016-04-04 09:15:00     NA
2016-04-04 09:16:00     NA
2016-04-04 09:17:00     NA
```

Your `NA.df` frame as the wrong timestamps for what you want to do.

```
index(NA.df) <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2016-04-01 09:15:00", tz = "Asia/Calcutta"), length.out = 3, by = "secs")
data2<-rbind(data1, NA.df)
> head(data2, 10)
                    SYMBOL
2016-04-01 09:07:31 108.40
2016-04-01 09:15:00     NA
2016-04-01 09:15:01 108.35
2016-04-01 09:15:01     NA
2016-04-01 09:15:02     NA
2016-04-01 09:15:03 108.35
2016-04-01 09:15:04 108.40
2016-04-01 09:15:05 108.20
2016-04-01 09:15:06 108.35
2016-04-01 09:15:07 108.25
```

Comment: Yes, I want it to be in the same column. But Why it is in the last. it should have been 09:15:00, 09:15:01, 09:15:03, and so on.

Comment: THis is how I created NA.df, min.ticks <- seq(as.POSIXct("2016-04-01 09:15:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                   as.POSIXct("2016-05-31 15:30:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), by="1 min")
  NA.df <- xts(x = data.frame(Empty=rep(NA, length(min.ticks))), order.by=min.ticks)
  indexTZ(NA.df) <- "Asia/Calcutta"
  NA.df<-NA.df[.indexday(min.df) %in% .indexday(data1)]
  NA.df<-NA.df["T09:15:00/T15:30:00"] What is the mistake here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126465/discussion-between-runjumpfly-and-fxquanttrader).